What `Source provides no match for variadic element at position 0 in target.(2322)` means?
Let's start with code TS Playground:
type Data = { [key: string]: Data } | string | number | boolean;
type ProtocolBlueprint = { args: Data[], result: Data };
type ProtocolDesc = { [key: string] : ProtocolBlueprint };

type MessageSender = number;
type AllowBeAsync<T> = Promise<T> | T;
type ProtocolListener<B extends ProtocolBlueprint> = (...args: [...B["args"], sender: MessageSender]) => AllowBeAsync<B["result"]>;

function registerInProtocol<D extends ProtocolDesc, K extends keyof D>(name: K, listener: ProtocolListener<D[K]>) : void
{
    // ...

    // I CAN'T CHANGE `implementation` TYPE FROM  ProtocolListener<ProtocolBlueprint>` TO `ProtocolListener<D[K]>` IS MUST STAY MORE BROAD ABSTRACT TYPE.
    const implementation: ProtocolListener<ProtocolBlueprint> = listener; // why this assignment is not valid? template paramter `D[K]` evaluates to `ProtocolBlueprint`.
    console.log(implementation);

    // ...
}


type Supported = 
{
    "countUsers": { args: [], result: number };
    "doesUserExist": { args: [id: number], result: boolean };
}
registerInProtocol<Supported, "countUsers">("countUsers", () => { return 23 });

Why I get this error message:

Type 'ProtocolListener<D[K]>' is not assignable to type 'ProtocolListener<ProtocolBlueprint>'. 
Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
Type '[...Data[], sender: number]' is not assignable to type '[...D[K]["args"], sender: number]'.
Source provides no match for variadic element at position 0 in target.(2322)

I can't wrap around why I get this error, like I mention in comment D[K] evaluates to ProtocolBlueprint, hence both types should match ProtocolListener<ProtocolBlueprint>. Also which variable is Source which Target (from last line in error message) in my situation?

Your assignment isn't valid as functions are contravariant in their parameters, so D[K] extends ProtocolBlueprint is backwards from what you need. You can see the problem in this playground. implementation must accept any list of arguments of Data type followed by a number, but listener might not handle that at all. So you get an error. Does that fully address the question? (note that "also" is an extra question and should be removed; if it says X is not assignable to Y, X is the source and Y is the target). If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

I get it. Please write it as answer I will accept that.

By the way, this is second time when you answer my question and problem is related somehow to how TS treat functions arguments. Thanks for help.

The error is TypeScript warning you about a type safety violation. Functions are contravariant in their parameter types (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) meaning that if you have a function type (x: X) => void, you can assign function of type (y: Y) => void to that type if X extends Y, not if Y extends X. The type direction goes backwards. This is often confusing for people but you can usually demonstrate fairly straightforward examples of why, as long as your functions actually hinge on the types for correctness.
Here's an example:
function registerInProtocol<D extends ProtocolDesc, K extends keyof D>(
    name: K, listener: ProtocolListener<D[K]>): void {
    const implementation: ProtocolListener<ProtocolBlueprint> =
        listener; // error!
    console.log(implementation);
    implementation("a", "b", 1); // okay
}
   
registerInProtocol<Supported, "countUsers">(
    "countUsers", (n) => { return n.toFixed().length } // okay
); 

If implementation is of type ProtocolListener<ProtocolBlueprint> then you're saying it is callable with arguments of type [...Data[], number]. So it has to be okay for me to call implementation("a", "b", 1) there.
Later, I can call registerInProtocol the way you did, but the callback actually expects and cares that it receives a number as its first argument.  After all, it's a ProtocolListener<Supported["countUsers"]>, which is (sender: number) => AllowBeAsync<number>.  So it has to be okay that I take that number and call toFixed() on it.
But lo and behold there is a runtime error:
//  error! n.toFixed is not a function

That's because (n) => { return n.toFixed().length } cannot safely be called with "a", "b", 1 as arguments. Oops.

That's the answer to the question as asked. You get  a compiler error because you're doing something unsafe. The implied question for how you fix it depends on your use case and is out of scope here. You'll need to think about what you want to do with implementation, and give it a more appropriate type. There is no safe "broad abstract type" that lets you call implementation. If you're not going to call it then you can just make it unknown. If you are going to call it you need to determine how.  More scrutiny there will be needed.
Playground link to code
